# Link image new tab didn't work in mozilla but working fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Here my code

```html
<a target="_blank" href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');">
  <img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/img/landing-page/terdaftar-kominfo.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: try without `target="_blank"`. `<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://pse.kominfo.go.id/tdpse-detail/295','_blank');">`

Comment: why use javascript to open a new window to an unrelated url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Javascript (`onclick`). The HTML tag `target="_blank"` already means "Open the link in a new tab" :

```html
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
</a>
```

Note that the link doesn't work here, in the snippet, probably because it's sandboxed. But try it from an HTML file and it will work.

Comment: thank you, now all working fine